# merge two different excels based on two conditions

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, indexing, merge

I have two excels. The first one is the dependent variable: data with **Date** & **station ID**, With date as the 'index' of dataframe, and station ID for headers. as shown as below,
[image]
The second one (independent variable) is the data I used to simulate the dependent variable(first excel above), also with **Date**, have the format as one column for year and the other two for month and date respectively. As shown in the image below
[image: independent variable image]

what I want is 1. skip the NaN value in the first excel.
2. add the value in the first table to the second excel based **on the same date** and **the same water monitoring station ID**
These are the codes I write until now, I am new to python and have been struggling for days.

````
import csv
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from numpy import size
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
# firstly, exclude those don't have value
# read csv file(2)
csvB4reflectance = pd.read_csv('GEEdownload.csv')
b4 = pd.read_csv('GEEdownload.csv',sep=',',parse_dates=['system:time_start'])
b4.set_index('system:time_start',inplace=True) #set index and change index type, to drop out
print(csvB4reflectance)
path = 'F:/72hourtimewindow/project/waterqualitydate/29UMT/'
excelorder = pd.read_excel(path+'Stationwithorder.xls',header = 0, index_col=0)
print(excelorder)
b41 = b4.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
print(b41)
# process this table, start to calculate when data in the form is not NaN
b41num = b41.to_numpy()
print(b41num)
# import excel order
for i in b41num:
    for j in i:
        if j == NaN:
            break
        else:
            if 
     print(j)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have came across this problem, the second chart need to be melted firstly!~ and then everything seems to be esay